# How to use interval to refresh data in reactive programming way?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to do refresh of the data every 5 seconds using **reactive programming writing.**

So I defined variable to hold the items I get from the server:

```
  items$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

And create another variable to get the request from the server.

for that I using `interval` for do it every 5 seconds:

```
interval(5 * 1000).pipe(
    startWith(0),
```

and using `exhaustMap` to prevent another requests until the current will be resolved.

After I call to the http I save it in `items$` and switch to `items$` because I subscribe in the html template. (I don't want to subscribe twice)

```
this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
        tap((r) => {
          console.log({ r });
          this.items$.next(r);
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.items$)
```

The problem is I get the results from `http` only once.

So how to make the `interval` still emit values and keep the idea of the refresh and switch to the data?

The full code [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-jackson-r04j3?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:216-740)

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: ` {{ reload | async | json }} `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  items$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  reload = interval(5 * 1000).pipe(
    startWith(0),
    exhaustMap(() =>
      this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
        tap((r) => {
          console.log({ r });
          this.items$.next(r);
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.items$)
      )
    )
  );

  url = "https://randomfox.ca/floof/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exhaustMap` operator is waiting for the inner observable to finish.

Move `switchMap` outside of `exhaustMap` and by doing so when the `http` finishes then it will switch to your `items$` observable stream.

```
 reload = interval(5 * 1000).pipe(
    startWith(0),
    exhaustMap(() =>
      this.http.get(this.url).pipe(
        tap((r) => {
          console.log({ r });
          this.items$.next(r);
        })
      )  
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.items$)
  );
```

Comment: [minor] you can replace `interval(5 * 1000)` + `startWith(0)` by a single operator: `timer(0, 5 * 1000)`